# How to replace Action delegate with a func delegate return a value to function

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, delegates, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I Have a function called as CompleteDownload Which takes int parameter and i want to print the percentage in this function

```
public void CompletedDownload(int percentage)
{    
    Console.WriteLine(mID+":"+percentage+"% Loading is Completed");
 }
```

and i have a function :

```
public void LoadProcedure(int n,Action<int> inAction)
    {   
      // LoadingDisplay loadingDisplay=new LoadingDisplay(n);
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(i==n/4)
            {   

                inAction(i);


            }
        }
     }
```

i want to return i value to Completeddownload Function using func delegate what is the approach

```
Loading loading=new Loading();
loading.LoadProcedure(100,display.CompletedDownLoad);
```

and also help me in main how to specify it.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to clarify why using `Func<…>` is not an option?

Comment: How to use it in above context sir can u specify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you do not seem to need to do anything with the response.  As a result, rather than attempting to return a value from your `CompletedDownload` method, you can process your action and simply break your loop if the condition is met.

```
public void LoadProcedure(int n, Action<int> inAction)
{
    // LoadingDisplay loadingDisplay=new LoadingDisplay(n);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i == n / 4)
        {
            inAction(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This will run your action, exit the loop, and return to the invoking method.

If you absolutely need to return the input variable that triggered the action, simply change `LoadProcedure`'s return type from a void to an int and return the result.

```
var result = loading.LoadProcedure(100,display.CompletedDownLoad);

public int LoadProcedure(int n, Action<int> inAction)
{
    // LoadingDisplay loadingDisplay=new LoadingDisplay(n);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i == n / 4)
        {
            inAction(i);
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

There's no need to change `inAction` to a `Func<>` because you don't do any calculation in the inAction currently.

Comment: Sir how can i repalce action delegate with func delegate for same example

Comment: @Rock your current example doesn't support a Func use case, but I added an additional example for returning the value that triggered the callback.